# Navigating JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been trying in vein to find a solution but nothing is coming up. Due to restrictions, have to build a mobile navigation system from a JSON object given to me by the proprietary server. They are allowing jQuery 1.12.4 but no other frameworks can be used or even the updated jQuery 3. Can't load PHP, Python or any other languages. So have to find either a pure javascript or jQuery 1.12.4 solution.

There will be a variable number of menu items and variable number of sub-menu items. I know you can access through bracket notation ***(can't use dot notation as the keys have dots in them from the server)*** but how do you go about accessing with variables or building it in a loop.

example i'm trying to get the inner object L.3.170 but need to build the bracket reference variably. and making a "back" feature from a string.

build the following REF from a string "L.1.171~L.2.170", initial is to split on the tilde and build the REF from a loop but not finding any examples on how to do that. I found a few eval ones but they don't seem to work.

REF to build: OBJ.root['L.1.171']['L.2.170']

sub-menu to build: OBJ.root['L.1.171']['L.2.170']['L.3.170']

replacing the literal brackets with variable ones and there will be a variable depth to the sub menus.

all of the "L" key names are unique so is there some kind of find function (like with arrays)? Nothing is coming up or working on how to find a sub object inside the JSON.

JSON (OBJ) from Server:

```
{
    "root": {
        "SubCount": 4,
        "L.1.22": {
            "img": "",
            "CategoryID": 635,
            "SubCount": 4,
            "L.2.4": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 692,
                "SubCount": 1,
                "L.3.4": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 229, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.10": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 213,
                "SubCount": 5,
                "L.3.6": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 46, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.7": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 48, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.8": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 49, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.9": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 50, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.10": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 95, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.14": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 212,
                "SubCount": 3,
                "L.3.12": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 53, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.13": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 55, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.14": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 98, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.22": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 211,
                "SubCount": 7,
                "L.3.16": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 46, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.17": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 49, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.18": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 50, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.19": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 52, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.20": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 54, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.21": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 95, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.22": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 98, "SubCount": 0 }
            }
        },
        "L.1.100": {
            "img": "",
            "CategoryID": 689,
            "SubCount": 6,
            "L.2.38": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 225,
                "SubCount": 14,
                "L.3.25": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 612, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.26": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 773, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.27": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1174, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.28": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 135, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.29": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 451, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.30": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1169, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.31": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 403, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.32": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 136, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.33": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 133, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.34": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 134, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.35": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 138, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.36": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 137, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.37": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 132, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.38": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 130, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.53": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 217,
                "SubCount": 14,
                "L.3.40": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 108, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.41": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 611, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.42": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 772, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.43": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 448, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.44": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 103, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.45": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 404, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.46": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 106, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.47": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 105, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.48": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 107, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.49": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 104, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.50": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 266, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.51": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1168, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.52": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1173, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.53": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 112, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.68": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 219,
                "SubCount": 14,
                "L.3.55": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 613, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.56": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 775, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.57": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 450, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.58": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 144, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.59": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 146, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.60": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 400, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.61": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 145, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.62": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 151, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.63": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 150, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.64": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 147, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.65": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1170, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.66": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1176, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.67": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 143, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.68": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 141, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.83": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 220,
                "SubCount": 14,
                "L.3.70": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 614, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.71": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 774, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.72": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1171, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.73": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1175, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.74": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 453, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.75": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 153, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.76": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 399, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.77": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 154, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.78": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 155, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.79": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 161, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.80": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 160, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.81": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 156, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.82": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 159, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.83": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 158, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.98": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 698,
                "SubCount": 14,
                "L.3.85": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 776, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.86": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1167, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.87": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 253, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.88": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 608, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.89": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 473, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.90": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 256, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.91": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 258, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.92": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 259, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.93": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 260, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.94": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 254, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.95": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 255, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.96": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 262, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.97": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1172, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.98": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 397, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.100": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 218,
                "SubCount": 1,
                "L.3.100": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 208, "SubCount": 0 }
            }
        },
        "L.1.122": {
            "img": "",
            "CategoryID": 870,
            "SubCount": 6,
            "L.2.108": {
                "img": "", "CategoryID": 871, "SubCount": 6,
                "L.3.103": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 883, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.104": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 885, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.105": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 873, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.106": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 886, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.107": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 872, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.108": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 884, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.109": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 886, "SubCount": 0 },
            "L.2.110": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 872, "SubCount": 0 },
            "L.2.111": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 884, "SubCount": 0 },
            "L.2.112": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 876, "SubCount": 0 },
            "L.2.122": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 672,
                "SubCount": 9,
                "L.3.114": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 839, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.115": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 210, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.116": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 277, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.117": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 639, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.118": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 870, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.119": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 282, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.120": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1191, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.121": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 932, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.122": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 332, "SubCount": 0 }
            }
        },
        "L.1.171": {
            "img": "",
            "CategoryID": 672,
            "SubCount": 9,
            "L.2.124": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 839, "SubCount": 0 },
            "L.2.125": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 210, "SubCount": 0 },
            "L.2.132": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 277,
                "SubCount": 6,
                "L.3.127": { "img": "1173128.Chat Icon.png", "CategoryID": 1211, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.128": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1159, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.129": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1084, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.130": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1150, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.131": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1138, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.132": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1119, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.145": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 639,
                "SubCount": 12,
                "L.3.134": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 122, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.135": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 121, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.136": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 512, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.137": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 124, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.138": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 125, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.139": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 127, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.140": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 878, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.141": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 877, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.142": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 880, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.143": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 879, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.144": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 874, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.145": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 282, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.152": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 870,
                "SubCount": 6,
                "L.3.147": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 871, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.148": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 886, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.149": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 872, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.150": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 884, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.151": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 876, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.152": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 672, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.158": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 282,
                "SubCount": 5,
                "L.3.154": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 122, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.155": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 512, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.156": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 121, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.157": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 124, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.158": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 127, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.165": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 1191,
                "SubCount": 6,
                "L.3.160": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1184, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.161": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1186, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.162": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1185, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.163": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1187, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.164": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1189, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.165": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1190, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.170": {
                "img": "",
                "CategoryID": 932,
                "SubCount": 4,
                "L.3.167": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 936, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.168": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1181, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.169": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 331, "SubCount": 0 },
                "L.3.170": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1182, "SubCount": 0 }
            },
            "L.2.171": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 332, "SubCount": 0 }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Object.keys()` might be able to help you out here. You could get an array of those 'L' key names and navigate accordingly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Thank you...That only returns the "root" key, the recursive ones i've found just list them out but don't keep the dimention. unless i'm missing an option that keeps the depth.

Comment: Well, for every object inside your object, you can fetch those keys. So if your JSON is in var named `data`, you could simply do `Object.keys(data.root)` that would come back with `['SubCount','L.1.22','L.1.100',...]`. Unfortunately, you'll have to do some work to fetch keys, traverse, fetch new keys, traverse, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might getter better answers if you are a bit more explicit about what you want in the end. I'll try and fill in some of the things I think you are looking for.

If you have a string like `"L.1.171~L.2.170"` you can simply split and reduce to get the object with something like:

```js
var OBJ = { "root": { "SubCount": 4, "L.1.22": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 635, "SubCount": 4, "L.2.4": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 692, "SubCount": 1, "L.3.4": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 229, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.10": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 213, "SubCount": 5, "L.3.6": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 46, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.7": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 48, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.8": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 49, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.9": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 50, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.10": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 95, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.14": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 212, "SubCount": 3, "L.3.12": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 53, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.13": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 55, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.14": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 98, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.22": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 211, "SubCount": 7, "L.3.16": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 46, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.17": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 49, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.18": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 50, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.19": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 52, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.20": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 54, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.21": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 95, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.22": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 98, "SubCount": 0 } } }, "L.1.100": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 689, "SubCount": 6, "L.2.38": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 225, "SubCount": 14, "L.3.25": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 612, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.26": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 773, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.27": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1174, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.28": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 135, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.29": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 451, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.30": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1169, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.31": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 403, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.32": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 136, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.33": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 133, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.34": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 134, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.35": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 138, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.36": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 137, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.37": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 132, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.38": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 130, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.53": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 217, "SubCount": 14, "L.3.40": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 108, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.41": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 611, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.42": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 772, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.43": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 448, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.44": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 103, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.45": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 404, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.46": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 106, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.47": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 105, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.48": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 107, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.49": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 104, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.50": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 266, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.51": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1168, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.52": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1173, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.53": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 112, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.68": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 219, "SubCount": 14, "L.3.55": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 613, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.56": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 775, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.57": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 450, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.58": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 144, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.59": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 146, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.60": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 400, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.61": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 145, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.62": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 151, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.63": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 150, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.64": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 147, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.65": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1170, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.66": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1176, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.67": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 143, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.68": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 141, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.83": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 220, "SubCount": 14, "L.3.70": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 614, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.71": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 774, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.72": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1171, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.73": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1175, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.74": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 453, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.75": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 153, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.76": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 399, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.77": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 154, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.78": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 155, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.79": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 161, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.80": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 160, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.81": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 156, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.82": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 159, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.83": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 158, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.98": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 698, "SubCount": 14, "L.3.85": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 776, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.86": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1167, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.87": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 253, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.88": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 608, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.89": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 473, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.90": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 256, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.91": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 258, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.92": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 259, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.93": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 260, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.94": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 254, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.95": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 255, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.96": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 262, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.97": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1172, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.98": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 397, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.100": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 218, "SubCount": 1, "L.3.100": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 208, "SubCount": 0 } } }, "L.1.122": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 870, "SubCount": 6, "L.2.108": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 871, "SubCount": 6, "L.3.103": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 883, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.104": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 885, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.105": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 873, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.106": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 886, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.107": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 872, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.108": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 884, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.109": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 886, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.2.110": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 872, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.2.111": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 884, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.2.112": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 876, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.2.122": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 672, "SubCount": 9, "L.3.114": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 839, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.115": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 210, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.116": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 277, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.117": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 639, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.118": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 870, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.119": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 282, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.120": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1191, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.121": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 932, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.122": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 332, "SubCount": 0 } } }, "L.1.171": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 672, "SubCount": 9, "L.2.124": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 839, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.2.125": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 210, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.2.132": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 277, "SubCount": 6, "L.3.127": { "img": "1173128.Chat Icon.png", "CategoryID": 1211, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.128": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1159, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.129": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1084, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.130": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1150, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.131": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1138, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.132": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1119, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.145": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 639, "SubCount": 12, "L.3.134": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 122, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.135": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 121, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.136": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 512, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.137": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 124, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.138": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 125, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.139": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 127, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.140": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 878, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.141": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 877, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.142": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 880, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.143": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 879, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.144": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 874, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.145": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 282, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.152": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 870, "SubCount": 6, "L.3.147": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 871, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.148": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 886, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.149": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 872, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.150": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 884, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.151": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 876, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.152": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 672, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.158": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 282, "SubCount": 5, "L.3.154": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 122, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.155": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 512, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.156": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 121, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.157": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 124, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.158": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 127, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.165": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1191, "SubCount": 6, "L.3.160": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1184, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.161": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1186, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.162": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1185, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.163": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1187, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.164": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1189, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.165": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1190, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.170": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 932, "SubCount": 4, "L.3.167": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 936, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.168": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1181, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.169": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 331, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.170": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1182, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.171": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 332, "SubCount": 0 } } }}

let key_string = 'L.1.171~L.2.170'
let keys = key_string.split('~')

let found = keys.reduce((a, c) => a[c], OBJ.root)
console.log(found)
```

There are probably lots of ways to find a particular object given a key. One way would be to flatten your structure into one object with a single level of keys. Then you could get a particular object by key for example:

```js
var OBJ = { "root": { "SubCount": 4, "L.1.22": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 635, "SubCount": 4, "L.2.4": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 692, "SubCount": 1, "L.3.4": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 229, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.10": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 213, "SubCount": 5, "L.3.6": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 46, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.7": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 48, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.8": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 49, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.9": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 50, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.10": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 95, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.14": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 212, "SubCount": 3, "L.3.12": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 53, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.13": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 55, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.14": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 98, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.22": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 211, "SubCount": 7, "L.3.16": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 46, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.17": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 49, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.18": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 50, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.19": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 52, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.20": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 54, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.21": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 95, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.22": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 98, "SubCount": 0 } } }, "L.1.100": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 689, "SubCount": 6, "L.2.38": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 225, "SubCount": 14, "L.3.25": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 612, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.26": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 773, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.27": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1174, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.28": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 135, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.29": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 451, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.30": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1169, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.31": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 403, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.32": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 136, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.33": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 133, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.34": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 134, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.35": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 138, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.36": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 137, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.37": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 132, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.38": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 130, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.53": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 217, "SubCount": 14, "L.3.40": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 108, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.41": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 611, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.42": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 772, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.43": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 448, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.44": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 103, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.45": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 404, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.46": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 106, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.47": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 105, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.48": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 107, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.49": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 104, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.50": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 266, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.51": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1168, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.52": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1173, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.53": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 112, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.68": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 219, "SubCount": 14, "L.3.55": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 613, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.56": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 775, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.57": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 450, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.58": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 144, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.59": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 146, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.60": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 400, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.61": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 145, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.62": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 151, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.63": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 150, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.64": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 147, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.65": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1170, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.66": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1176, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.67": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 143, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.68": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 141, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.83": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 220, "SubCount": 14, "L.3.70": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 614, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.71": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 774, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.72": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1171, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.73": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1175, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.74": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 453, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.75": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 153, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.76": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 399, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.77": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 154, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.78": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 155, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.79": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 161, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.80": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 160, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.81": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 156, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.82": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 159, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.83": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 158, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.98": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 698, "SubCount": 14, "L.3.85": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 776, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.86": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1167, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.87": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 253, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.88": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 608, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.89": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 473, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.90": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 256, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.91": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 258, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.92": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 259, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.93": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 260, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.94": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 254, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.95": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 255, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.96": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 262, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.97": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1172, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.98": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 397, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.100": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 218, "SubCount": 1, "L.3.100": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 208, "SubCount": 0 } } }, "L.1.122": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 870, "SubCount": 6, "L.2.108": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 871, "SubCount": 6, "L.3.103": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 883, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.104": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 885, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.105": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 873, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.106": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 886, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.107": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 872, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.108": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 884, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.109": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 886, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.2.110": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 872, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.2.111": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 884, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.2.112": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 876, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.2.122": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 672, "SubCount": 9, "L.3.114": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 839, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.115": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 210, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.116": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 277, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.117": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 639, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.118": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 870, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.119": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 282, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.120": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1191, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.121": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 932, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.122": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 332, "SubCount": 0 } } }, "L.1.171": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 672, "SubCount": 9, "L.2.124": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 839, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.2.125": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 210, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.2.132": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 277, "SubCount": 6, "L.3.127": { "img": "1173128.Chat Icon.png", "CategoryID": 1211, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.128": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1159, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.129": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1084, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.130": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1150, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.131": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1138, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.132": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1119, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.145": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 639, "SubCount": 12, "L.3.134": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 122, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.135": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 121, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.136": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 512, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.137": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 124, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.138": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 125, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.139": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 127, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.140": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 878, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.141": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 877, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.142": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 880, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.143": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 879, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.144": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 874, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.145": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 282, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.152": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 870, "SubCount": 6, "L.3.147": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 871, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.148": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 886, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.149": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 872, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.150": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 884, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.151": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 876, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.152": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 672, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.158": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 282, "SubCount": 5, "L.3.154": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 122, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.155": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 512, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.156": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 121, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.157": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 124, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.158": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 127, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.165": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1191, "SubCount": 6, "L.3.160": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1184, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.161": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1186, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.162": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1185, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.163": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1187, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.164": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1189, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.165": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1190, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.170": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 932, "SubCount": 4, "L.3.167": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 936, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.168": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1181, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.169": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 331, "SubCount": 0 }, "L.3.170": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1182, "SubCount": 0 } }, "L.2.171": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 332, "SubCount": 0 } } }}


function make_lookup(obj, map_obj = {}) {
  let children = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => k.startsWith('L.'))
  if (!children) return map_obj
  children.forEach(c => {
    map_obj[c] = obj[c]
    make_lookup(obj[c], map_obj)
  })
  return map_obj
}

let myMap = make_lookup(OBJ['root'])

// lookup L.2.170
console.log(myMap['L.2.170'])

// lookup L.3.169
console.log(myMap['L.3.169'])
```

It shouldn't be hard to convert the above to something that returns an array of keys rather than the objects themselves, but it's not clear what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to first map the data structure you are retrieving to something that can be used more easily when building some DOM for your menu.

In the snippet below the keys starting with `L.` are turned into an array of menu items where the key becomes available as `id` on the menu item. All subsequent keys inside of the menu item are then mapped to a `children` array which also contains menu items. This data structure allows you to loop through the list of menu items and their respective sub-menus more easily.

```js
let responseData = getData()
let menuItems = parseMenuItems(responseData.root)

document.body.appendChild(renderMenuItems(menuItems))

function parseMenuItems (input) {
  return Object.keys(input)
    .filter(key => key.startsWith('L.'))
    .map(menuId => {
      let menuItem = Object.assign({
        id: menuId,
        children: parseMenuItems(input[menuId])
      }, input[menuId])
      
      menuItem.children.forEach(childItem => {
        delete menuItem[childItem.id]
      })
      
      return menuItem
    })
}

function renderMenuItems (menuItems) {
  let ul = document.createElement('ul')
  
  menuItems.forEach(menuItem => {
    let li = document.createElement('li')
    li.textContent = menuItem.id
    
    if (menuItem.children.length > 0) {
      li.appendChild(renderMenuItems(menuItem.children))
    }
    
    ul.appendChild(li)
  })
  
  return ul
}

function getData () {
  return {
    "root": {
      "SubCount": 4,
      "L.1.22": {
        "img": "",
        "CategoryID": 635,
        "SubCount": 4,
        "L.2.4": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 692,
          "SubCount": 1,
          "L.3.4": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 229, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.10": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 213,
          "SubCount": 5,
          "L.3.6": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 46, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.7": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 48, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.8": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 49, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.9": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 50, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.10": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 95, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.14": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 212,
          "SubCount": 3,
          "L.3.12": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 53, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.13": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 55, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.14": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 98, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.22": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 211,
          "SubCount": 7,
          "L.3.16": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 46, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.17": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 49, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.18": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 50, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.19": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 52, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.20": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 54, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.21": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 95, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.22": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 98, "SubCount": 0 }
        }
      },
      "L.1.100": {
        "img": "",
        "CategoryID": 689,
        "SubCount": 6,
        "L.2.38": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 225,
          "SubCount": 14,
          "L.3.25": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 612, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.26": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 773, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.27": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1174, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.28": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 135, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.29": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 451, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.30": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1169, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.31": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 403, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.32": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 136, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.33": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 133, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.34": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 134, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.35": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 138, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.36": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 137, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.37": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 132, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.38": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 130, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.53": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 217,
          "SubCount": 14,
          "L.3.40": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 108, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.41": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 611, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.42": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 772, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.43": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 448, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.44": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 103, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.45": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 404, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.46": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 106, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.47": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 105, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.48": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 107, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.49": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 104, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.50": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 266, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.51": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1168, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.52": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1173, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.53": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 112, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.68": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 219,
          "SubCount": 14,
          "L.3.55": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 613, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.56": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 775, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.57": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 450, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.58": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 144, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.59": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 146, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.60": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 400, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.61": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 145, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.62": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 151, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.63": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 150, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.64": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 147, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.65": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1170, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.66": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1176, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.67": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 143, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.68": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 141, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.83": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 220,
          "SubCount": 14,
          "L.3.70": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 614, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.71": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 774, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.72": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1171, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.73": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1175, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.74": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 453, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.75": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 153, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.76": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 399, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.77": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 154, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.78": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 155, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.79": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 161, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.80": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 160, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.81": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 156, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.82": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 159, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.83": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 158, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.98": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 698,
          "SubCount": 14,
          "L.3.85": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 776, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.86": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1167, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.87": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 253, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.88": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 608, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.89": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 473, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.90": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 256, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.91": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 258, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.92": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 259, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.93": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 260, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.94": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 254, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.95": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 255, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.96": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 262, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.97": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1172, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.98": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 397, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.100": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 218,
          "SubCount": 1,
          "L.3.100": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 208, "SubCount": 0 }
        }
      },
      "L.1.122": {
        "img": "",
        "CategoryID": 870,
        "SubCount": 6,
        "L.2.108": {
          "img": "", "CategoryID": 871, "SubCount": 6,
          "L.3.103": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 883, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.104": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 885, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.105": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 873, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.106": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 886, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.107": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 872, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.108": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 884, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.109": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 886, "SubCount": 0 },
        "L.2.110": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 872, "SubCount": 0 },
        "L.2.111": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 884, "SubCount": 0 },
        "L.2.112": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 876, "SubCount": 0 },
        "L.2.122": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 672,
          "SubCount": 9,
          "L.3.114": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 839, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.115": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 210, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.116": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 277, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.117": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 639, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.118": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 870, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.119": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 282, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.120": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1191, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.121": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 932, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.122": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 332, "SubCount": 0 }
        }
      },
      "L.1.171": {
        "img": "",
        "CategoryID": 672,
        "SubCount": 9,
        "L.2.124": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 839, "SubCount": 0 },
        "L.2.125": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 210, "SubCount": 0 },
        "L.2.132": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 277,
          "SubCount": 6,
          "L.3.127": { "img": "1173128.Chat Icon.png", "CategoryID": 1211, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.128": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1159, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.129": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1084, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.130": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1150, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.131": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1138, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.132": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1119, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.145": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 639,
          "SubCount": 12,
          "L.3.134": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 122, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.135": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 121, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.136": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 512, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.137": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 124, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.138": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 125, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.139": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 127, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.140": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 878, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.141": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 877, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.142": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 880, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.143": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 879, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.144": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 874, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.145": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 282, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.152": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 870,
          "SubCount": 6,
          "L.3.147": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 871, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.148": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 886, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.149": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 872, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.150": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 884, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.151": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 876, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.152": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 672, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.158": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 282,
          "SubCount": 5,
          "L.3.154": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 122, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.155": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 512, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.156": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 121, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.157": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 124, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.158": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 127, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.165": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 1191,
          "SubCount": 6,
          "L.3.160": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1184, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.161": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1186, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.162": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1185, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.163": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1187, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.164": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1189, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.165": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1190, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.170": {
          "img": "",
          "CategoryID": 932,
          "SubCount": 4,
          "L.3.167": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 936, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.168": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1181, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.169": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 331, "SubCount": 0 },
          "L.3.170": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 1182, "SubCount": 0 }
        },
        "L.2.171": { "img": "", "CategoryID": 332, "SubCount": 0 }
      }
    }
  }
}
```